# Python - measure longest subsequence of a certain value in a list with tolerance for error

Tags: python

Given a list of integers `[0,0,0,1,1,0,2,2,0,1,0,0,2,1,2,2,2,2,1,...]`, I need to calculate the longest subsequence of elements of which x% of the elements are n, i.e. there is a tolerance whereby a subsequence which contains less than 1 - x% values other than n is still counted as an unbroken subsequence of n's.

I have used the following one-liner to get the longest subsequence where all values are n, but I don't know where to go from here:

```
longest_subsequence_0 = max((len(l) for n, l in itertools.groupby(list) if n == 0))
```

If anyone could steer me in the right direction it would be much appreciated :D

Comment: I think that, after you calculate your `longest_subsequence`, you can have a loop to expand this subsequence to both sides one item at a time. You can then calculate your x% in every iteration and stop when it is broken. I'm not sure this will work in the case the sequence you are looking for is made up of several smaller broken pieces though. You might have to write it as a loop to begin with to cover this scenario as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a sliding window changing size and computing the %. If above threshold, record the window size if this one is larger than the previous stored one.

```
def longest_sub(list, n, threshold):
    largest_window = 0
    for i in range(len(list)+1): # from i 
        for j in range(i+1,len(list)+1): # to j
            window_len = len(list[i: j]) # store window size
            if window_len > largest_window: # if inspected window > largest found yet
                if list[i:j].count(n)/window_len*100 > threshold: # if percentage above threshold
                    largest_window = window_len # new largest_window
    return largest_window

longest_sub([0,0,0,1,1,0,2,2,0,1,0,0,2,1,2,2,2,2,1], 0, 30) # 9 
longest_sub([0,0,0,1,1,0,2,2,0,1,0,0,2,1,2,2,2,2,1], 0, 80) # 3
```

Comment: I tried this and it works, but since the lists are quite long (1,000+ elements) it can be pretty slow. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

---

I have this

```
import numpy as np

MAX = 10
a = 5
LEN = 100
threshold = 0.3
tolerance = 0.05

x = list(np.random.choice(list(range(MAX)), size=LEN))

window = LEN

largest = 0
while window > 1 and largest == 0:
    for i in range(0, LEN-window+1):
        ratio_of_a = x[i:i+window].count(a)/window
        if ratio_of_a > threshold - tolerance:
            largest = window

    window -= 1

print(f"Largest sequence found {largest}")
```

Pretty brute force, i used `a` instead of `n` also sorry for the confusion :)

Comment: I think the greedy algorithm doesn't work here; for example, if the sequence is `[1, 1, 2, 1, 1]` and the sequence has to have less than 25% non-1s, you'd find `[1, 1]`, reject the 2 because it would result in 33% non-1s, and hence stop before finding that the whole sequence works.